# Facebook Connect and HTTP basic authentication

Tags: facebook, basic-authentication

I am working on a site that uses Facebook Connect for user login/creation. I have a development server which is used for QA, and I'd like it to be password protected. We wanted to use HTTP basic authentication, but that seems to break Facebook Connect (it falls in a loop). Does anybody know why that may be happening?

I believe that basic authentication is done on a browser basis, and all the communication between Facebook and our site is done in the browser of the user. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook Connect uses iFrame inside iFrame hack to overcome cross domain boundaries limitation (see http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Cross_Domain_Communication for details). My guess is that when Facebook redirects to the callback page (xd_receiver.htm) it fails because later requires basic authentication.

Comment: This is similar to my suspicions. However, I always understood that Basic Auth credentials are saved by the browser and used when needed. Why would an IFrame be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

More information needed on the "falls in a loop".  But based on your question, from what I've read is that facebook connect will create a random password on account creation, and if they are logging in over basic auth, it will need to be changed to match up(http://www.boonex.com/unity/forums/topic/facebook-connect-error-.htm)
But you don't specify if that's the way you are using FBconnect.
Are you requiring basic auth to get to the point of FBconnect account link/create?

Or are you using FBconnect to create the login for the basic auth?

How are you requiring basic auth? Server type?

Does everything work without requiring basic auth?